# Make the outer layout aware of the current route in react static

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-static, react-static-router

My app has a structure like this:

```js
const App = () => (
    <Router>
      <Layout>
        <Routes />
      </Layout>
    </Router>
)
```

However, I would like to make the layout depend on the type of page that is loaded.

I know that there is a `this.props.location` inside the rendered routes, but I cannot access it from the outside.

I read about lifting state up, but I don't know whether that's possible with the `<Routes />` component.

How can I get the current route in my Layout component?

Comment: Hi, have you tried using Routes with children render prop like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54055652/does-routes-break-hrm-in-react-static?